# Print text associated with a value

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that collects data and analyses any trends.
What I'm trying to do is figure out how to output the text value associated  with the numerical value.

Example:

```
Apples      7
Oranges     2
Pears       0
Mangoes     4
```

I grab the highest values by doing the following..

```
= LARGE(B:B, 1)
= LARGE(B:B, 2)
= LARGE(B:B, 3)
```

My desired output would look like..

```
Top 3
-------
Apples 7
Mangoes 4
Oranges 2
```

Which then changes dynamically according to the data values in column B.

But how do I then output the text value associated with this?

Answer (score 1):

With the following formula you can accomplish that.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(DATA!A1:B4, "SELECT A, B ORDER BY B DESC LIMIT 3")
```

### Explained

The `QUERY` formula selects the two columns and orders them descendingly according to column B. Then it limits the result to three rows (top 3).

### Screenshot

*data*
[image]

*result*
[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Top 3 results](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FFCZpkBJOfpPCbMnpq4HfEBOtYEobzkYYKNwox00t6Y/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0):

Question shows OP is not expecting ties but since these are often a possibility a slightly 'safer' query might be:

```
=QUERY(A1:B7, "SELECT A, B where B>="&large(B:B,3)&" ORDER BY B desc, A")
```

This may output more than three results.